# Virus that causes memory to buffer up for hard disk tasks?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, 64-bit, virus

What could this be?

When explorer.exe starts Autoplay and starts scanning files, explorer's memory usage shoots up to 6GB (I have 8GB, 64 bit Windows 7).

When I run file recovery software such as Recuva or Pandora Recovery, Recuva being 64 bit shoots up to nearly 7GB and I cannot even complete the process since the swap file kicks in and the system becomes too slow to use. Pandora is 32 bit and it is usable, but still shoots up to ~3.8GB of memory.

Anything that seems to scan the harddrive seems to have this effect.

I have ran ComboFix, malwarebytes, and a few others and nothing was found.

Thanks

Comment: Just as a precaution, have you tested the related hardware?

Comment: Check the Task Manager's Processes tab, does any item look unusual? Anything funky going on in the Startup list of MSCONFIG?

Comment: Good thinking @Moses maybe he/she should run memtest86?

Comment: No unusual items, I disabled all non MS services and start-up items. I will try memtest86.

Comment: Nope, memory is fine.

Comment: Is re-installing Windows 7 from scratch an option? If you have a spare hard drive laying around then I would install it there and see if you can re-create the symptoms on a fresh install. Also make sure to do all the updates in case it was an update that cause this.

Comment: @user22902 Just a tip, if you would like the attention of a specific user then please use `@username` so that they get notified when posting because that person might not be actively monitoring your question. thanks